# MySQL query two lines as one

Tags: mysql

I am working with data in CFDB (a database for contact forms) in CF7 (a forms plugin) in Wordpress. The data from the tables is organized in one table with the following columns. Each submission contains fields numbered from 0 to 9999 with #9999 always containing the login information for the submission. The submit_time variable is essentially the ID for the form submission.

```
ID      submit_time     form_name   field_name      field_value field_order file
7881    1454460768.7523 Insurance   provider        UBH         0           NULL
. . . 
7900    1454460768.7523 Insurance   InsuranceCard   card.pdf    19          [BLOB - 71.8 KiB]
7901    1454460768.7523 Insurance   Submitted Login email@e.com 9999        NULL
```

The file column is usually NULL unless there is a uploaded file.  I am trying to make a query that will list submissions with uploads in this particular format:

```
date                message_title   from_login  
1454460768.7523     InsuranceCard   email@e.com
```

So potions of the data are extracted from these two queries:

```
SELECT submit_time AS date, field_name AS message_title
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE field_order = 9999    

SELECT field_value AS from_login
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE file IS NOT NULL
```

How do I put them together to produce a list in this format:

```
date                message_title   from_login  
1454460768.7523     InsuranceCard   email@e.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one submission at one timestamp (and there is no timestamp at which no file was uploaded) you can use the following query:

```
SELECT s.submit_time AS date, s.field_name AS message_title, (SELECT e.field_value FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits e WHERE e.submit_time = s.submit_time AND e.field_order = 9999) as from_login
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits s
WHERE s.file IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [logical and](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) in your query:

```
SELECT submit_time AS date, field_name AS message_title, field_value AS from_login
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE field_order = 9999 
  AND file is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Will only work if file is not null on the *same* record where field_order is 9999 - which probably won't ever happen, from the question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT submit_time AS date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN file is NOT NULL THEN field_name END) AS message_title, 
       MAX(CASE field_order WHEN 9999 THEN field_value END) AS from_login
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE field_order = 9999 or file is NOT NULL
GROUP BY submit_time
HAVING MAX(file) is NOT NULL
```

(Note: assumes there will only be one attachment per submission.)

Comment: @CraigTucker: Glad I could help.